# Can a melspectrogram feature set be filtered for onset detection?

Tags: signal-processing, librosa

I have a features [here](http://aum.dartmouth.edu/~mcasey/AlgoRhythms_Data/features/track000.melspec) which is a 128 mel bin melspectrogram. I want to write a beat tracker and for this I need to use onset detection. Can a melspectrogram be filtered for beats or should I use something like [this](http://aum.dartmouth.edu/~mcasey/AlgoRhythms_Data/features/track000.beat_melspec) (a beat_melspectrogram).

I've already been able to successfully read a melspectrogram for a given track. However the beat_melspec doesn't seem to match up with the timecode for a given track.

Comment: For matching the timecode of the beat melspec you will have to provide more details than you do now. How does the code look like for computing the timecode, what do you expect to get, and how is what you observe differ?

Answer (score 1):

Librosa contains a basic beat track estimator. https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.beat.beat_track.html